# making selectizeInput function in Rshiny to print out all selected variables at once

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am new to `Rshiny` and practising how to use `reactive values`, `reactive expressions` and `selectizeInput`. I would like to have all brands printed at once after pressing the button without the sentence "**The brands selected are as follows:** " to be printed multiple times:
here is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("This is a Test"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput('brand', label = 'Car brand',
                     multiple = T, choices = mtcars %>% rownames(),
                     selected = NULL, width = '100%',
                     options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button')))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("show_brands", "Show brands"),
      textOutput("brands")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    brandname = NULL,
    mpgdata = NULL
  )
  
  

    
  output$brands <- renderText({
    allbrands <- values$brandname()
    paste("The brands seleted are as follows: ", allbrands)
  })
  
  values$brandname <- eventReactive(input$show_brands, {
    input$brand
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and here is the output after selecting three of the brands:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap `input$brand` in another `paste()` call:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("This is a Test"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      'brand',
                      label = 'Car brand',
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      choices = rownames(mtcars),
                      selected = NULL,
                      width = '100%',
                      options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'))
                    )
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    actionButton("show_brands", "Show brands"),
                    textOutput("brands")
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$brands <- renderText({
    paste("The brands seleted are as follows: ", paste(input$brand, collapse = ", "))
  }) |> bindEvent(input$show_brands)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: There is no need to use `reactiveValues`

Comment: So when shall we use the expressions like this in which multiple reactive values are defined in the following way: values <- reactiveValues(
    brandname = NULL,
    mpgdata = NULL
  )

Comment: Typically `reacitveValues` are used if you need a reactive variable that can be modified in several places regarding your code.